# C++の編集に適したLinuxで使えるIDEまたはエディターはありますか？

Tags: c++, linux

最近C++を始めたのですが、Linux環境で使える無料のIDE(エディター)はありませんか?
自動補完に特化したIDE(エディター)が良いです。cmakeとかはあまり使わなそうです。

Linuxの環境はArch Linux
コンパイラーはGCCを使っています
(質問が荒くてすみません)

Comment: こんな記事がありますので参考に。[What are the best IDEs for C++ on Linux?](https://www.slant.co/topics/1411/~best-ides-for-c-on-linux)

Comment: @Yukidaruma-dev IDEといっても機能性が千差万別なので、「こういう機能があると嬉しい」みたいなのがあるとオススメしやすそうと思いました。とはいえ勉強をし始めたばかりだと何があると嬉しいのかも判断しにくいですよね……。

Comment: 自動補充はとても欲しいですね。cmakeとかはあまり使わなそうです。 自動補充に特化したIDE(エディター)が良いです。

Comment: 細かい話になりますが自動「補完」だと思います。「補充」だと意味が違ってきます。

Comment: すみません... 追記でQt GUIの開発をします

Answer (score 2):

私は、たいていは [Visual Studio Code](https://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/products/visual-studio-code/) (VS Code) に C++ 用の拡張機能を入れて使っています。

設定すれば、フォーマット、自動補完、定義ジャンプ、ブレイクポイント等が使えます。

C++ 用のカスタマイズについて公式ドキュメントがあるので参考にしてください：https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Answer (score 2):

私はQt贔屓なので、Qt Creatorをおすすめします。GUIアプリのフレームワークとして知られるQtですが、その開発環境であるQt Creatorは、GUI関係無しのコンソールプログラムの開発にも対応できます。[新しいプロジェクト]をクリックするとダイアログボックスが表示されて、[非Qtプロジェクト]を選び、[C++アプリケーション]を選択してプロジェクトを作成すると、最も基本のHello, worldプログラムができます。自動補完はもちろん、Ctrl+Spaceを押して補完候補を表示したり、F2キーで定義ジャンプしたり、Ctrl+Shift+Rでシンボル名の変更や、その他Alt+Enterで各種リファクタリングや便利機能が利用できます。デバッガや静的解析機能（Clang-Tidy and Clazy analyzer）も統合されています。マルチプラットフォーム対応で、Windows、macOS、Linuxで同じように使えます。

※ 知り合いにはCLionを愛用している人もいます。そちらも参考にされるといいかと思います。（私は使ったことありません）

Comment: CLionは有料でした（30日試用可能）

Comment: 自動補完出る時間に少しラグがありますけど、Qtを使った開発をしたかったので丁度良かったです!